# Shell Script to monitor mount points

Tags: shell, unix

I have a scenario where I need to monitor the mount points of multiple servers through single script. Currently I am stuck at this point:

```
#!/bin/bash
ser1 = `ssh server1 df -F ext3 -k | \
        grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | \
        grep "/$" | awk '{ print $4}' | \
        cut -d'%' -f1`

echo $ser1
```

While running the script, the prompt asks for password. I want to add multiple servers in the list. Is it possible to automatically fetch the utilization without giving passwords every time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You need to set up password less connectivity.

Below article helps you in setting up one for you.

http://www.unixarena.com/2012/07/how-to-configure-password-less.html

Answer (score 0):

The password prompt is most likely for the ssh authorization at the remote system. A very secure way to avoid this is to use *Public/Private Key Authorization*:

If not done already, you need to generate a key pair using

```
$ ssh-keygen  # generates a new Public/Private Key Pair
```

After having done this, you can copy your *Public Key* to the remote system using

```
$ ssh-copy-id you@remote-server
```

Now, when trying to log in, your computer authorizes itself using your *Private Key*, without the need to type in a password:

```
$ ssh you@remote-server  # now works without password
```

[This Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) might help you in understanding *Public/Private Key Authorization*.